# Getting the same css values(color) before and after mouse hover on an image

Tags: css, selenium

I am getting the same css values(color) before and after mouse hover on an image below is my selnium script:

```
List<WebElement> shortcuts = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#shortcutlist_primary a img"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
for(WebElement er : shortcuts) {
    System.out.println("Color of a shortcut before mouse hover: "   + er.getCssValue("color"));
    action.moveToElement(er).perform();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    System.out.println("Color of a shortcut after mouse hover : "   + er.getCssValue("color"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your locator you are referring to an `<img>` tag which hasn't got color CSS attribute. Try it again after you deleted the `img` at the end of it.